# Follow layout except content

Tags: c++, qt, layout, qt5

Right now I have [image] where the tablewidget and calendar resizes as the window is expanded/contracted. But as you can see my table (2 columns, x rows) also follow the layout. How do I break out of this? What I want is the calendar and table widget to resize as the form expands and the two columns filling up the entire widget. Something like this:[image]

Comment: Just put the tables in a own container each and resize contents given your needs.

Comment: @SebastianLange I put them in frames, and I resize with something along the lines of `ui->widget->setcolumnwideth(0, ui->widget->width / 2)` the thing is the widget doesnt resize with my containers...which defeats the purpose. If it does resize, i get the results from pic 1

Comment: Check if your parentwidget has the ``resizeChildWidgets`` flag set. You could also subclass your container widget and/or connect to the resize event to manually resize the children.

Comment: That was the issue :P thanks

Answer (score 1):

You have to set size policies for these widgets with `setSizePolicy()` method - here is [docs](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-5.0/qtwidgets/qwidget.html#sizePolicy-prop) . And chose behavior you desire from this [enum](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-5.0/qtwidgets/qsizepolicy.html#Policy-enum)

For example, if you want tablewidget to take all available space:

```
tablewidget->setSizePolicy(QSizePolicy::Expanding,QSizePolicy::Expanding);
```